# ruby (5) on rails - SQLite3::SQLException: no such table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, sqlexception

I created another table in my SQLite database but unfortunately cannot access it through the rails console. I added one row of data through the GUI (DB Browser for SQLite) and am now trying to access it through but it gives me the error
"ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table:"

In my schema I can see it already:

```
create_table "user_information", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "charity_name", limit: 100
t.string "res_exp_contact_name", limit: 50
t.string "res_exp_contact_email", limit: 100, default: "", null: false
t.string "grants_contact_name", limit: 50
t.string "grants_contact_email", limit: 100, default: "", null: false
t.boolean "submission_status_res_exp"
t.integer "submission_status_grants"
t.string "category"
t.string "username"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.string "password_digest"
t.index ["username"], name: "index_user_information_on_username"
end
```

This is how the terminal looks like:

```
ck$ rails console
Running via Spring preloader in process 8442
Loading development environment (Rails 5.1.4)
Cannot read termcap database;
using dumb terminal settings.
irb(main):001:0> user = UserInformation.first
   UserInformation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "user_informations".* FROM 
   "user_informations" ORDER BY "user_informations"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  
[["LIMIT", 1]]
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: 
user_informations: SELECT  "user_informations".* FROM 
"user_informations" ORDER BY "user_informations"."id" ASC LIMIT ?
    from (irb):1
```

Does anyone know a solution to this? I'm grateful for any tips! :-)

Comment: `create_table "user_information"` vs `SELECT  "user_informations"` => the `create_table` use a singularized version, but Rails (by default) compute the table's name as pluralized. You can either manually set the table's name in the `UserInformation` model (not recommended) or rollback then rename the table in your migration to `create_table "user_informations"` (!!! This will remove all the existing data in this table, create a new migration to rename the table if you want to keep the existing data)

Answer (score 3):

Solved it. The answer is that you always name tables in plural so I added a migration that renamed my table from "user_information" to "user_informations". Now it works!